# Add todays date when opening saved email template

Tags: microsoft-outlook, vba

I want to add a message and the date when ever I open an email template I have saved.

I could only manage to get to the below bit of code:

```
Private Sub adddate()
    .Item.Subject = "Prep Status Report " & Format(Date, "dd/MM/yyyy")
End Sub
```

How can I improve this so that it works as intended.

The subject line should read : `Prep Status Report 10/12/2018` if run on 10th December

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could insert your line of code into the code for Method 2 at "2 Quick Methods to Create New Emails from a Template with Outlook VBA" at https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/2-quick-methods-create-new-emails-template-outlook-vba/

- In your line of code, change `.Item` to `NewMail`.
- in the code from Datanumen, change the file path to your template's file path.

Also, you could add the macro to your Quick Access Toolbar, if you want to run it with one click.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, not completely what I was after but its good enough.